# Why is the constructor changed?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Why does the constructor change from Foo to Object after adding a prototype? How can I get access to the original constructor?

Code:

```
function Foo() {}
var foo1 = new Foo();
console.log('foo1: ' + foo1.constructor);

Foo.prototype = {}
var foo2 = new Foo();
console.log('foo2: ' + foo2.constructor);
```

Output:

```
foo1: function Foo() {}

foo2: function Object() {
    [native code]
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vDCTJ/

Comment: How come, after overwriting, the constructor 1 is still the called one? --> http://jsfiddle.net/ttqjV/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because you gave Foo a brand new object for its prototype, and you didn't set that object's "constructor" property.

```
Foo.prototype = { constructor: Foo };
```

Instantiated function objects get an object for their "prototype" property that's already initialized that way.

Comment: Thats actually what i've been doing, but i've been just writing the entire constructor in the prototype :P

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

`foo1` was created with the initial `Foo.prototype` object which has a `constructor` reference to `Foo`, which it inherits.

In contrast, `foo2` does inherit from the empty object which you set `Foo.prototype` to before instantiating it. And that object inherits its `constructor` property from `Object.prototype`, therefore `foo2.constructor === Object`.