# In Javascript, Why setting prototype on constructor function changes .constructor value on its instance?

Tags: javascript

```
function Human(){
  this.job = 'code'
}

//Human.prototype = {feeds: 'Pizza'};

var developer = new Human();

console.log(developer.constructor);
```

Above console logs

```
function Human() {
this.job = 'code';
}
```

When i uncomment the line `Human.prototype = {feeds: 'Pizza'};` it console logs

```
function Object() {
  [native code]
}
```

Why setting prototype on constructor function, affects who is the constructor on object created by the constructor?

**Another example:**

```
function LivingBeing() {
  breathes: 'air';
}

function Human(){
  feeds: 'Pizza';
}

//Human.prototype = new LivingBeing();

var developer = new Human();
console.log(developer.constructor);
```

With commented like it says constructor is Human, when uncommented it says LivingBeing. Why constructor traverses further when something valid found on prototype?

**I thought to add one more level to this**

```
function AThing(){
  this.say = function(){return 'I am thing';};
}

function LivingBeing() {
  breathes: 'air';
}

LivingBeing.prototype = new AThing();

function Human(){
  feeds: 'Pizza';
}

Human.prototype = new LivingBeing();

var developer = new Human();
console.log(developer.constructor);
```

Now its says developer's constructor is AThing. Can i say constructor goes as far as possible in the prototype chain?

Comment: exact duplicate of [Why is the constructor changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826535/why-is-the-constructor-changed)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't spot that while i am posting.

Answer (score 2):

`developer` has no *own* property named `constructor` therefore when you're asking for it, it's looked for in the prototype chain. Since the prototype is a plain Object, its constructor is the default object constructor `Object()`.

When you declare a new function like `function Human()`, JS creates an implicit object and populates `prototype` and `constructor` fields as follows:

```
X = {}
Human.prototype = X
X.constructor = Human
```

now, when you write `dev = new Human`, the internal `__proto__` property of `dev` is set to `X` and `dev.constructor` resolves to `X.constructor`, which is `Human`.

When you uncomment the "pizza" line, the code turns into the following:

```
Human.prototype = X
X.constructor = Human

pizza = {feeds:'Pizza'}
// pizza.__proto__ = {}
// pizza.constructor = pizza.__proto__.constructor = Object

Human.prototype = pizza
// note that pizza.constructor does NOT change

dev = new Human
// dev.__proto__ = Human.prototype = pizza

dev.constructor
// dev.constructor = dev.__proto__.constructor = pizza.constructor = pizza.__proto__.constructor = Object()
```

Answer (score 0):

### What is a constructor?

> Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's
>   prototype. Note that the value of this property is a reference to the
>   function itself, not a string containing the function's name. The
>   value is only read-only for primitive values such as 1, true and
>   "test".

### First Case:

The constructor of `developer` was the `function Human(){this.job = "code";}`.

### Second Case:

Since you are overriding the prototype to object, now the developer is an instance of `Object {}`.

The Console shows any native global objects, predefined in the implementationof javascript itself as `[native code]`. That is they don't reveal the implementation.

Comment: Yes, but developer is still created with the same Human constructor.

Comment: Yes, but when prototype of Human is changed, the object itself is changed.

Comment: You mean the function object